# Server.Transfer in Try-catch :Thread abort exception

Tags: try-catch, server.transfer, threadabortexception

What is the equivalent of

```
Response.Redirect("abc.aspx",false)
```

when i use Server.Transfer instead of Response.Redirect.I use false as the second param of Response.Redirect to stop receiving the ThreadAbort exception in a try catch block

I want to get rid of the Thread.Abort exception when i use Server.Transferis in a try catch block. Any thoughts ?

Comment: I'm pretty interested in why that exception is thrown in the first place and what the effects are of simply ignoring those exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Server.Execute` instead. Just as with passing false to `Response.Redirect`, you have to make sure that nothing undesirable happens when the rest of the code in the method you are in (and its calling methods) is executed.